# File upload using the API's

Tags: php, codeigniter

I had developed a website for my client and now the mobile team is developing the android app for them. For that, I created some API to get the data which will be initiated by the android developers.

Now, I need to upload the file(video or document) using the APIs. Link to my database and file to my specific folder.

Example API which I used to get the product details

http://xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxx/api/doctor_pitch_details?email=mahesh@gmail.com&password=123456789&product=22

can anyone help me how to do it.

Comment: Don't include your password in a GET request please.

Comment: Why have password in url?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use get use multipart and tell your android team to send data in multipart form so you can get a file at your end get file like

```
$user_photo = $_FILES['faile_param_name']['name'];
```

Comment: How the REST API can get file? Is it possible?? Can you write a tutorial or gist which demonstrate the complete example?? I am also interested in this.